# Right way to delete container

Tags: c++, containers

When destructing a class with a container in the class for example:

```
class randomClass
{
    ...
    private:
        queue<myClass*> *myQueue;
    ...
};
```

What is the correct why to delete the queue:

First option:

```
randomClass::~randomClass()
{
    delete myQueue;
}
```

Second option:

```
randomClass::~randomClass()
{
    while(myQueue.size() > 0)
    {
        myClass *tmp;
        tmp = myQueue->front();

        delete tmp;
        myQueue->pop();
    }

    delete myQueue;
}
```

Comment: The right way is to use a smart pointer, but failing that the second stops you from leaking memory.

Comment: The right way is usually `queue<myClass> myQueue;` You should think hard if you really need something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using regular pointers (as opposed to smart pointers) the second option is the one to use, because it prevents memory leaks.

A more C++ way of coding this would be using smart pointers (i.e. [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) or [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)) instead of plain pointers.  Then the first option would work correctly.

Finally, you may want to make the `myQueue` an object, instead of a pointer. This would free you from the need to write your destructor, along with a copy constructor and an assignment operator.

Comment: +1 or better still, unless there is a damn good reason to do so, avoid pointers *entirely* and just use `std:queue<myClass>`

Comment: Ok the thing is I am studying computer science and that is the way they learned me to program. They say you always need to make you objects a pointer en create them in your class delete them afterwards.
So do you have some advice?

Comment: @Ian I'm sure they mean "for the purposes of this particular learning exercise", not "in general", because containers have nice resource management code that frees you up from writing your own cleanup code.